# merge json results and use properties as pandas columns

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a Json and I'd like to merge the result objects together and have a dataframe that uses "properties" as columns (ID, Title, Site, Last edited time, Link, Status).

Here is what I tried:

```
    import pandas as pd
    import json
    data = json.load(open('db.json',encoding='utf-8'))
    df = pd.DataFrame(data["results"])
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(df["properties"])

    print(df2)
```

Here is the json: https://dpaste.com/GV94XD64Y

Here is the result I am expecting:

```
                Site          Last edited time                       Link Status ID       Title
0  stackoverflow.com  2023-01-16T20:44:00.000Z  https://stackoverflow.com   None  1      page 0
1  stackoverflow.com  2023-01-16T20:44:00.000Z  https://stackoverflow.com   None  1      page 1
```

Comment: those keys has different inner keys, how `Title` key with contents `"Title": {

            "id": "title",

            "type": "title",

            "title": [

              {

                "type": "text",

                "text": {

                  "content": "page 0"

                }

              }

            ]
` should be presented in df?

Comment: What's the result you are expecting? You can inspect it a bit by doing: df.properties.apply(pd.Series) and see what the result is. Here I see a dataframe with these headers, but I only see more dicts wrapped in a dataframe.

Comment: @mtjiran RomanPerekhrest I edited the question with the expected results but pd.Series resolved this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use apply `pd.Series` on properties:

```py
df2 = df.properties.apply(pd.Series)
```

Comment: Just apply pd.Series and you are good to go. In Pandas, whenever considering looping, reconsider. df.properties.apply(pd.Series)

Comment: it's even easier. df2 = df.properties.apply(pd.Series)

Comment: @mtjiran yep, stupid me, forgot to remove part for creating dataframe from collection)